# Write an SQL query selecting data from filtered Date columns

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, crosstab

i am trying to query a crosstab table/recordset in Access (tried ADO on excel sheet), where the columns are having dates in them e.g.

[image: Columns appearing as Dates]

if i want to pull a limited data having columns only for the Year 2014, how do i write such a query? Please note, these columns may vary.

Comment: Use a where clause in the SQL, `where year(dtInspectDate)=2014`

Comment: the columns are having week ending dates for 2014, 2015,2016 also. if i want to just limit the columns to only some particular year, then how do i do it using an sql query? i tried doing your suggestion but not getting any results.

IF you have a table like this, can you give me an example of how the sql query should look to pull only certain year columns?

p.s: I dont know what the dates may be.

Comment: select * from data where year(data.dtDate)=2014

Comment: so i tried as you said like this but get parameter textbox :

SELECT * 
FROM Data
WHERE YEAR (REPLACE(Data.["Week Ending " & "*" ],"Week Ending ","",1))=2014

what could be wrong?

Comment: year([Week Ending])=2014 is Week Ending the name of your field in the table?

Comment: If you see, each of the columns are having Text "Week Ending " as well as a Date in them e.g.

"Week Ending 10/02/13". Another thing to note is the date is actually in British dd/mm/yy format and not American mm/dd/yy format.

Comment: So are you trying to select from a date column i.e. select [Week ending 01-10-2014] from table or where the data is the date.

Comment: I want to select data from all such date columns I.e. "Select [Week Ending ??/??/??] From Table Where the year contained in them is 2014."

Answer (score 1):

something like this, there may be a simpler method though

```
Sub Akward_Query()

Dim strSQL As String
Dim strSQL2 As String
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim fld As ADODB.Field
Dim intYear As Integer

intYear = 2014

strSQL = "Select top 1 * from tbl_Test"

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

rst.Open strSQL, CurrentProject.Connection, 1

strSQL2 = "Select "

For Each fld In rst.Fields

    If InStr(1, fld.Name, "Week Ending") > 0 And InStr(1, fld.Name, intYear)>0 Then

        strSQL2 = strSQL2 & "[" & fld.Name & "],"

    End If

Next fld

If Right(strSQL2, 1) = "," Then strSQL2 = Left(strSQL2, Len(strSQL2) - 1)

strSQL2 = strSQL2 & " from tbl_Test"

End Sub
```

Comment: This is cool. But isn't there an SQL query that can be written on this crosstab to grab limited date columns? Unwinding the crosstab is not an alternative as there are 1008 rows and there are 165 such date columns i.e. after unpivoting, the rows become 165 * 1008 = 166320 rows.
Also i had to change this to as it was not detecting the year : 
    If InStr(1, fld.Name, "Week Ending") > 0 And Right(fld.Name, 2) = Right(intYear, 2) Then.....

Comment: you would add your pivot lines onto the SQL, that I've created.  So select x,y,z then you can do the pivot bit, you need to do some yourself :)

Comment: The initial idea is to limit the table data to contain only the few date columns for a particular year. Then Transform this recordset again on ACV values showing as Column headings now, counting the 1st occurrence of each ACV value (NA, 0, 1,2,3, etc., found under these date columns) in a row, for each unique item in 1st column. i am stuck with this quandary for quite some time. IF you can help me with this, i will be most grateful. If not, i still like to thank you for all your help. :)